# CustomUI not showing up in wix bootstrapper instead Microsoft framework showing

Tags: c#, wix

When I run the installer, it gives me a title that says Microsoft .NET Framework required for my project. When I accept the terms and condition of Microsoft  setup screen will get close soon.But in  uninstall folder of controlpanel I can see my project is installed .But actually when I check the system I can see my project is not installed.(none of the project folders or application is installed).
By project will run only in system having .Netframework4.6 .I am checking whether machine has it if not I am installing it.
My customUI is also built of 4.6 version

Comment: In bundle.wxs code is as follows:

Comment: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="sample" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Starkey" UpgradeCode="5a714642-7857-4582-8bae-80fd6d8ec77a">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload SourceFile='$(var.BootstrapperApplicationUI.TargetPath)' />

Comment: <Payload Name='BootstrapperCore.config' SourceFile='$(var.BootstrapperApplicationUI.ProjectDir)BootstrapperCore.config' />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

Comment: <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx4Full' />      
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\beta\bin\Release\sample.msi"  Id="BetaInstallId" Cache="yes" vital="yes"/>
      
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

Comment: <Fragment>
    <!-- Managed bootstrapper requires .NET as a dependency, since it was written in .NET.
       WiX provides a Bootstrapper for the bootstrapper. The fragment below includes .NET.
       For more information or examples see Heath Stewart's blog or the WiX source:
       http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications.aspx
       -->

Comment: <?define NetFx46MinRelease = 394254 ?>
    

       <!-- Get the release of the .NET V4 framework currently installed -->
    <util:RegistrySearch
          Id="NETFRAMEWORK4"
          Variable="NETFRAMEWORK4"
          Root="HKLM"
          Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
          Value="Release"
          Result="value" />

Comment: You should probably edit your original question and include the bundle code instead of trying to squish it into multiple unformatted comments. Not many people will take the time to read through the multiple comments.

Answer (score 0):

Well as your custom UI uses the .NET 4.6 it will install the .NET 4.6 BEFORE the bundle starts; hence you don't see your custom UI at first.

Also:
What happens in the log?

And what shows up in the "Add or remove programs"-section, the bundle or your msi?

What does the msi look like? Has it been installed at a location which you did not expect maybe?

Comment: This means you don't have to install the .NET 4.6 in your bundle! It is a prerequisite for your CustomUI.